# How do I go from string to Variable name?

Tags: c#, resources

I would like to access resources with different, but ordered names in order using a for loop. For Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {     
        ExtractImages();
    }

    static void ExtractImages()
    {
        Bitmap bmp;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            // Here I need something like: 
            // bmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.bg + i);

            bmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.bg0); // in order bg0..bg5
            bmp.Save("C:\\Users/Chance Leachman/Desktop/bg" + i + ".bmp");
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? It's basically trying to make a String go to a variable name. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ResourceManager.GetObject Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963f81yd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The **GetObject** method is used to retrieve *non-string* resources. These include values that belong to primitive data types such as Int32 or Double, bitmaps (such as a **System.Drawing.Bitmap** object), or custom serialized objects. Typically, the returned object must be cast (in C#) or converted (in Visual Basic) to an object of the appropriate type.

```
var bitmap = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("bg0") as Bitmap;
```

In for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   string bitmapName = "bg" + i;
   bmp = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(bitmapName) as Bitmap;
   if(bmp != null)
       bmp.Save("C:\\Users/Chance Leachman/Desktop/bg" + i + ".bmp");
}
```